# Property or field 'email' cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm trying to POST from a form within a Boostrap Modal.

Here's my form:

```
            <form role="form" id="emailForm" action="#" th:action="@{/emailSubmission}" th:object="${university}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="emailID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailID" th:value="*{email}" placeholder="Enter email"></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"  class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Register</button>
            </form>
```

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/emailSubmission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerEmail(@ModelAttribute("university") University uni, BindingResult result, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println(uni.getEmail());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And my University class:

```
public class University {

    private String email;

    public University(){
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Spring and can't figure out what's going wrong and why I'm receiving the error mentioned in the title.

Changing:

```
th:value="*{email}"
```

to:

```
th:field="*{email}"
```

gives me 'Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'university' available as request attribute' error.

Comment: Where is your GET RequestMapping?

Comment: My stupidity. I needed to add the model attribute into the '@GetMapping' in my NavController. Thanks @holmis83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the university object as an attribute to the model in your controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/index") 
public String login(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("university", new University()); 
    return "index"; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I have for your, hope it helps. If you don't understand just tell me, have a good night.

```
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .post(Entity.json(Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("attribute1", "value1")
    .add("attribute2", "value2")
    .build()));
```

or if you prefer:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
map.add("attribute1", "value1");
map.add("attribute2", "value2");
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  .post(Entity.form(map));
```

Now what I should do with it?

```
@POST
public Response post(JsonObject json) {
  return Response.ok(service.persist(MyFactory.create(json.getString("attribute1"), json.getString("attribute2"))).build();
}
```

Or of course if you prefer:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response post(@FormParam("attribute1") String attribute1, @FormParam("attribute2") String attribute2) {
  return Response.ok(service.persist(MyFactory.create(attribute1, attribute2))).build();
}
```

Comment: yeah I don't really understand what you're doing. Are you working around the functionality that Spring/Tyhmeleaf has?